# MVC html string field 2 way binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller that have a field `HtmlContents` with data like `<input type=text>`

I know how to render that text as html using:

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.HtmlContent)
```

What I need now is that when the user type some thing and the form submit
the value of `Model.HtmlContent`update so I need some thing like `@html.textboxfor(a=>a.HtmlContent)` that return the updated value that what I mean by 2 way binding.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `Html.TextBoxFor`?  What didn't work?

Comment: the field is html string i need to render if the field contain <input type=checkbox> if i used textboxfor it will give me a textbox with the value '<input type=checkbox>' inside i need to render that field to show a checck box